# The last couple scroll lines are hidden behind the footer. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scroll

I have data in tables that require scrolling.   I also have a fixed footer  at the bottom of the display.    The last few items in the table are hidden behind the footer when scrolling to the bottom of the table.   Is there a simple way to limit the bottom of the scroll so that it falls outside the footer when scrolling to the last items in the table?

The application is responsive for display on computer, iphone and ipad.

Relevant code Application.html.erb:

```
   <body>  
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <div class="main-container" >
         <%= yield %>
         <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
         <!--%= debug(@horses) if Rails.env.development? %-->
      </div>
   </body>
```

Relevant CSS code - main-container:

```
  body > .main-container {
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 60px 15px 0em;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    background-color:#B0BD92;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
```

Relevant code - footer.html.erb

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
     <div class="navbar-footer">
        <a id="logo">Copyright xxxxx</a>
     </div>
  </nav>
```

There is currently no CSS that relates to the class "navbar-footer"

Thanking you in advance for your help

Comment: Is footer fixed height?

Comment: The footer is taking the defaults of navbar (45?).   I had it defined fixed in class navbar-footer but it is commented out at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this one because I have not received an answer.   I have taken the footer off to get around the issue.